# How Do I compile a xcode project for cydia

Tags: iphone, xcode, cydia

I have designed a app that I wish to release to via cydia.

What a easy way to compile my xcode project into a binary ready for cydia??

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link it shows about the method for compiling for cydia submission

http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a repo or send them to MMi's collection.

To make a repo: [here](http://www.saurik.com/id/7) or [here](http://modmyi.com/forums/cydia-support/402221-how-make-cydia-repository.html)

upload to modmyrepo : at modmyi.com/mmi/